# Adding controller to jQuery script

Tags: jquery

I just wrote jQuery script to flip Divs, yet I can't figure away to create a controller.

Like click at a portion to bring the first div etc.

Example: click on link 1 to get div 1, click link 2 to get div 2, etc.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval ("animateFunc()",3000);
});

function animateFunc (){
    var currentDiv = $("#divsContainer div.current");
    var nextDiv = currentDiv.next();

    if (nextDiv.length == 0) {
        nextDiv = $("#divsContainer div:first");
    };

    currentDiv
        .css({ left: 0 })
        .removeClass("current")
        .animate({ left: "100%" }, 1000);

    nextDiv
        .css({ left: "-100%" })
        .addClass("current")
        .animate({ left: 0 }, 1000);
};
```

And here is a fiddle for the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/e8uz3/1/

Thanks all!

Comment: What do you mean by `create a controller`?

Comment: Don't use ids that start with/are numbers

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan let's say it's a slide show, I need to create a controller or something like index so you jump to first or second images etc.

Comment: take a look at how [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) does it